# flex full screen external

Tags: apache-flex, hyperlink, fullscreen

I have a flex application that goes into fullscreen mode when a user selects from a list (selects a project to view).

all works great except if the user clicks on a link ( e.g a PDF document) this opens in a new window (all good) and when user attempts to go back to previous page they cannot access the page. they need to Alt+TAB to get to fullscreen window.

client will get lost, any idea on getting the browser to open the new link in full screen mode, as i think (hope) this will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is now way to force browser to switch from pdf page to fullscreen flash app.
Instead, you can show pdf file inside your app by using some lib like FlexPaper. In that case you can insert any control to close this pdf, or you can handle back button on your page with HistoryManager.